# What is AWS CodeArtifact? What is it and what is it useful for

Tags: aws-codeartifact

I have some question to a service called AWS CodeArtifact?

What is it and what is it useful for.

Any links to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From [1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/introducing-aws-codeartifact-a-fully-managed-software-artifact-repository-service/)

> AWS CodeArtifact is a fully managed software artifact repository service that makes it easy for organizations of any size to securely store, publish, and share packages used in their software development process. CodeArtifact eliminates the need for you to set up, operate, and scale the infrastructure required for artifact management so you can focus on software development. With CodeArtifact, you only pay for what you use and there are no license fees or upfront commitments.
>
> AWS CodeArtifact works with commonly used package managers and build tools such as Maven and Gradle (Java), npm and yarn (JavaScript), pip and twine (Python), making it easy to integrate CodeArtifact into your existing development workflows. CodeArtifact can be configured to automatically fetch software packages from public artifact repositories such as npm public registry, Maven Central, and Python Package Index (PyPI), ensuring teams have reliable access to the most up-to-date packages.
>
> IT leaders can use AWS CodeArtifact to create centralized repositories for sharing software packages approved for use across their development teams. CodeArtifact’s integration with AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) provides them with the ability to control who has access to the packages. Further, CodeArtifact’s support for AWS CloudTrail gives leaders visibility into which packages are in use and where, making it easy to identify packages that need to be updated or removed. CodeArtifact also supports encryption with AWS Key Management Service so customers can control the keys used to encrypt their packages.

Product Page: [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/)

Answer (score 0):

It is an artifact repository from AWS. Refer this - 
https://aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/